# A variant of Travelling Salesman: Is it NP-complete if its sub-problems are NP-complete?

Tags: np-complete, traveling-salesman

Suppose there is a travelling salesman who wants to travel through N cities in k countries(k <= N). For convenience, he will travel all the cities within a certain country and then move to another. In each country, he wants to find out the shortest simple path to traverse through all the cities.[Classic TSP problem]

Q1. Suppose moving to another country costs nothing. Is that still a NP-complete problem? Any suggestion for a proof?

Q2. (There could be connections with certain costs between two cities in two different countries.) Suppose the salesman has to visit the countries (but not cities) in a certain order. Is that still a NP-complete problem? Any suggestion for a proof?

---

(Precisely, I should have used "NP-hard problem". I hope you can translate it into the decision version.)

Q1:
It is intuitive that a general TSP instance can be reduced to this problem for k = 1. What I know about is that you can reduce a general instance of a known NP-c problem into a "special" instance of the problem that you wish to reduce to. However, I think "k=1 (with N)" is a very special case that it is much harder than instances when k > 1. That's why I am not quite certain if this intuitive approach is correct.

"This is a dump of an exercise problem, not a question." I feel sorry for my algorithm teacher. I made this exercise up for a similar situation in my research (not in the area of algorithm for sure). If I let k = 1, the instance got reduced to seems to be the hardest instance which I doubt if it is general. Since the sub-problems are NP-c (in decision version), let the cost for jth country with m cities be $T_j(m)$, then $\Sigma_k T_j(m)$ is much smaller than $T(N)$. Also, the problem is not that hard when k = N. (k is part of the input?)

"Is it NP-complete if its sub-problems are NP-complete?" (So I made up the problem.) If so, that intuitive approach seems correct.

Q2:
I think it is kind of related to Q1. I didn't post it because I tend to solve it on my own.(Hints are welcome.) If you solve it, I may have to consider putting you as a coauthor later :).

---

Thanks

Comment: Hint: Consider the case $k = 1$.

Comment: This is a dump of an exercise problem, not a question. If you have a specific question regarding the wording of the problem or concrete steps in your own attempts at solving the problem, feel free to edit accordingly and we can reopen the question. See also [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/470/) for our homework policy, and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594) for a relevant discussion. You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/). If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: The case where there's only one country is classical TSP so, yes, this is NP-hard.

Comment: It is intuitive that a general TSP instance can be reduced to this problem for k = 1. What I know about is that you can reduce a general instance of a known NP-c problem into a "special" instance of the problem that you wish to reduce to. However, I think "k=1 (with N)" is a very special case that it is much harder than instances when k >= 1. That's why I am not quite certain if this intuitive approach is correct.

Actually my real question is the 2nd half : "Is it NP-complete if its sub-problems are NP-complete?" (So I made up the problem.) If so, that intuitive approach seems correct.